# Question regarding a Composition of functions

Tags: functions, continuity

Last year I took a course Metric and Topological Spaces where I was asked to find an example where $f(x) \to b$ as $x \to a$ and $g(y) \to c$ as $y \to b$ but $g(f(x)) \not \to c$ as $x \to a$.
I never found an example and my head hurts thinking about it.

Can you give such an example or disproof such an example exists?

Comment: Why do you think such an example exists?  If $g(y)\to c$ as $y\to b$, why can't we apply it with $y:=f(x)$?

Comment: Last year, this was a question from a metric and Topological Spaces course that I took. But I never found an answer.

Comment: @Berci say $f:\Bbb{R}\to\Bbb{R}$ is a constant function with value $b$. Let $g:\Bbb{R}\to\Bbb{R}$, $g(y)=c$ for $y\neq b$ and $g(b)=c+1$ for example. Then, $g(y)\to c$ as $y\to b$ but for all $x\in\Bbb{R}$, $g(f(x))=g(b)=c+1$. I assume here of course that we're working with the definition of limits using punctured neighborhoods.

Comment: peek-a-boo has pointed out the only problem. If $f \ne b$ on some deleted neighborhood of $a$, or every neighborhood of $c$ contains $g(b)$ as well (either $g(b) = c$ or the points are not separable), then you can prove $g\circ f(x) \to c$ as $x \to a$. But if $f(x) = b$ for some $x \ne a$ in every neighborhood of $a$, and $c$ has a neighborhood not including $g(b)$, then $g\circ f(x)$ will not converge as $x \to a$.

Comment: @Berci Many thanks to you. I had a similar thought but I dismissed it too quickly.